# flatten result from linq query

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am using a linq query to get the names of all properties of all classes that derive from some specified class like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all visible properties of classes deriving from the specified base type
    /// </summary>
    private HashSet<string> GetDerivedPropertyNames(Type baseType)
    {
        // get all property names of the properties of types that derive from the base type
        var propertyNames =
            from type in baseType.Assembly.GetTypes()
            where type.IsSubclassOf(baseType)
            select Array.ConvertAll(type.GetProperties(), property => property.Name);
        // the hashset constructor will filter out all duplicate property names
        return new HashSet<string>(propertyNames);
    }
```

however this does not compile because the result of the linq query is an `IEnumerable<string[]>` whereas I wanted to have an `IEnumerable<string>`. how do I flatten the results into a single `IEnumerable<string>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd want `SelectMany`:

```
var propertyNames = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes()
 .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType))
 .SelectMany(type => type.GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name));
```

Possibly, including the Distinct step at once:

```
var propertyNames = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes()
 .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType))
 .SelectMany(type => type.GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name))
 .Distinct();
```

Comment: is Distinct O(n) like the HashSet constructor then?

Comment: @mtijn You can bet on it. Or you can profile it. Note, that, strictly, inserting from an IEnumerable into a collection is going to be O(n) _regardless of the collection type_. You probably meant: are you sure "Distinct won't go O(n*n) in the worst case". You can bet on it. Why would MS (or Mono) make such a bad mistake implementing _that_?